# What is the set of all functions from ℤ to ℤ?

Tags: mathematics, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

In David Deutsch's classic paper *Quantum theory, the Church-Turing principle and the universal quantum computer* (1985), Deutsch writes on p. 99:

> [image: C(ℱ) itself, also known as the set of recursive functions, is denumerable and therefore infinitely smaller than the set of all functions from ℤ to ℤ.]

(I thought that this might be in typo [in the original publication](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1985.0070), but it is also present in the version that was [retypeset in 1999](http://gretl.ecn.wfu.edu/%7Ecottrell/ope/archive/0305/att-0257/01-deutsch85.pdf) which is easily findable on the Internet.)

Since ℤ=ℤ, what is "the set of all functions from ℤ to ℤ?"

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ can be both the domain and the range of a function. So why is $\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) between two sets (say $A,B$) is simply a binary relation that associates to every element of the first set $A$ *exactly* one element of the second set $B$. Therefore, a function can be represented as a set $G$ of ordered pairs $(x,y), x \in A, y \in B$, satisfying the following: each element of $A$ appears exactly once in this set (to make sure there are no repetitions and that a single element cannot be mapped to two different outputs, i.e., this map *is* a function).

Now, to count the total number of functions between two sets we need to count the number of unique sets (of the form $G$ above) that can be constructed. One can show that the number of functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$ (see, for example, this [intuitive answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223240/how-many-distinct-functions-can-be-defined-from-set-a-to-b)).

Do the same for $A = \mathbb{Z} = B$ but beware of their cardinalities (and realize that this set is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set), see for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837223/is-the-set-of-all-functions-mathbb-n-to-mathbb-q-uncountable)).

**Update (from the comments)**: The notation ``set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$'' is shorthand for $\{f | f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\}$, i.e., all functions whose domain and range is $\mathbb{Z}$ (or subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: but ℤ and ℤ are the same number, are they not? Or is "ℤ to ℤ" shorthand for saying "all integers" ?  If that is true, whey not just say "in ℤ?" Or is it saying "from any integer to any other integer?"

Comment: @vy32 It is a shorthand for the set of *all* integers. This notation is ubiquitous (pretty much every math textbook ever written) so I wouldn't blame the author. Basically, this means that the set of "inputs" to the function is $\mathbb{Z}$ and so is the set of "outputs". But since $\mathbb{Z}$ also means any subset of it, it could be any *collection* of integers (including a single integer mapped to a single integer). Does that answer your question?

Comment: — yes, that answers my question!  If you could add it as an answer, I will accept it. I do not blame the author. I blame myself for not having taken enough math classes.

Comment: @vy32 Updated. I don't think anyone needs to be blamed here :) That, I guess, is the purpose of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to a two point set $\{0,1\}$. The cardinality of the set of all functions between these two sets is $2^{|\mathbb{Z}|}$.

Now ask yourself is the power set of $ \mathbb{Z}$ countable. If the answer is NO then the answer to your question is also a NO.